# I'm having trouble changing directories using python

Tags: python

Whenever I change directories using this program I wrote, it changes to the directory but then displays the message, "Directory not found." I think it might have to do with the order that I wrote everything in, but I can't find what's wrong. Any tips?

```
if command == ("cd"):
    changedDIR = input("Directory name: ")
    os.chdir(changedDIR)
    if not os.path.exists(changedDIR):
        print("Directory not found.")
        commandLine()
```

Comment: I think `os.chdir()` only takes absolute paths, not relative ones. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Works fine with Python 3 for me. What do you input as the directory name?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this

`os.getcwd()`

to check the directory exists or not :)

Comment: `os.getcwd()` returns the current working directory; it does not tell you if a directory exists.  If that is not what you mean, I think you should clarify.